# im trying to use if condition but i cannot get it to work xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios

im trying to use a simple if condition to equate the title of the annotatio but it is not working can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong over here ,

```
if([annotation title] == @"Parking")
        {
        pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        }
```

when i print the titles it displays ok

```
NSLog(@" these are the titles %@",[annotation title]);
```

but when i try to match it using if condition it doesnt work

any help would be deeply appreciated

Thanking you in advance for any suggestions or help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `isEqualToString:@"Parking"`

so replace with this:

```
if([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Parking"])
{
    pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
}
```

Comment: can we equate to more than one value like in other languages like 
if( title == "parking" || title == "car") ?

Comment: Sure you can. You might want to buy this book for future reference: http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0321566157/ref=redir_mdp_mobile/186-3555604-6642003

Answer (score 2):

When you do a comparison of two `NSString*` objects using the `==` operator, you're actually comparing their *pointers* rather than their *values*. If you want to compare the *values* of two objects, you have to call their `isEqual:` function instead.

```
if([[annotation title] isEqual: @"Parking"])
{
     pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare NSStrings with the `isEqualToString:` method:

```
if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Parking"])
    {
    pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    }
```